# JPA : Restrict query result number | Number of rows returned

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have a requirement to return max 10 result at a time. I used Criteria Builder to build the query and applied `setMaxResults(10)` to restrict the returned rows.

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Customer> q = cb.createQuery(Customer.class);
Root<Customer> c = q.from(Customer.class);
q.select(c);
q.distinct(true);
List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<>();

if(name != null && !name.trim().isEmpty()) {
  criteria.add(cb.like(cb.upper(c.get(Customer_.firstName)), name));
}
if(surname != null && !surname.trim().isEmpty()) {
  criteria.add(cb.like(cb.upper(c.get(Customer_.lastName)), surname));
}

if(username != null && !username.trim().isEmpty()) {
  criteria.add(cb.like(cb.upper(c.get(Customer_.userId)), username));
}
if (criteria.size() == 0) {
  throw new ValidationException("search criteria not provided");
}
else if (criteria.size() == 1) {
  c.where(criteria.get(0));
}
else {
  c.where(cb.and(criteria.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
}
return em.createQuery(q).setMaxResults(10).getResultList();
```

But debugging the SQL query I could see that the limit is applied to the outer query, i.e From my understanding, First all the result is fetched then top 10 is selected from the first result. This looks very inefficient.

```
org.hibernate.SQL : 
  select * from (
    select distinct
      customer0_.part_id as part_id1_9_,
      customer0_.ref_no as ref_no2_9_,
      customer0_.name as name3_9_,
      customer0_.fiscal_code as fiscal_code4_9_,
      customer0_.surname as surname5_9_,
      customer0_.prod_type as prod_type6_9_,
      customer0_.role as role7_9_,
      customer0_.userid as userid8_9_
    from vw_gdpr_cust_data customer0_
    where (upper(customer0_.name) like ?)
  )
  where rownum <= ?
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [%ISM%]
```

Could someone explain, how row limit can be implemented in an efficient manner.

Comment: Isn't this an Oracle limitiation? As far as I know Oracle has not "classic" LIMIT keyword, therefore the rownum solution is used. However for that to work one has to create a list of results first and then select the first N values.
So your problem is not the LIMIT, but the DISTINCT. Without that the query would probably not be nested.

Comment: So does that mean in Oracle there is no efficient way to select limited rows and in above question can the `rownum` be applied to inner query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle DB version 11g and older for limiting results (Top-N query) a query should have outer derived table and `ROWNUM`. Outer derived table is required to do sorting (`ORDER BY`) or applying `DISTINCT` before `ROWNUM`.

The following query has an error:

```
select * 
from emp 
where ROWNUM <= 5 
order by sal desc;
```

The correct version of this query:

```
select * 
from ( select * from emp 
       order by sal desc ) 
where ROWNUM <= 5;
```

See https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-rownum-and-limiting-results

JPA `setFirstResult(offset)` also requires outer derived query:

```
select * 
from ( select * 
       from ( select * from emp 
              order by sal desc ) 
       where ROWNUM <= 8 ) /* last result */
where ROWNUM >= 5; /* first result */
```

In Oracle 12c new syntax for Top-N and paging queries was introduced:

```
select * 
from emp 
order by sal desc
offset 4 rows fetch next 4 rows only;
```

Consider using `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect`.

Comment: Is there any workaround or hacks for this drawback.

Comment: I don't think Top-N or paging queries cause performance problems in Oracle. Check the execution plan for the query you want to optimize. `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR select * from ( select distinct customer0_.part_id ...)`, `SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display)`.